# SHKTwitterCallbackUrl Puzzle ...?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, twitter

How to set this `SHKTwitterCallbackUrl` through the Twitter Developer site ...[image]

I'm using the `ShareKit` to Integrate the facebook, twitter, mail option. facebook works fine but I am not able to configure twitter.

Or where we can find this "Registered Callback URL" I am able to fine API Key but how can I get "Registered Callback URL".

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the my problem by devoting the time into this for "Registered Callback URL". used any url (not be present as the valid one) its totally depend on you.

"Registered Callback URL". examplelike...

> http://www.appname.com/done

the only point is you enter the same "Registered Callback URL". value as you enter during the registration process.

Thanks EveryOne...